# Print part of a comma-separated field using AWK

Tags: shell, awk

I have a line containing this string:

```
$DLOAD , 123 , Loadcase name=SUBCASE_1
```

I am trying to only print `SUBCASE_1`. Here is my code, but I get a syntax error.

```
awk -F, '{n=split($3,a,"="); a[n]} {printf(a[1]}' myfile
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `cut -d '=' -f 2 myfile`

Comment: @Cyrus, IMHO, even I was thinking on it, but that wouldn't check if there is `,` present in line or not and may end up to false positive results, after seeing OP's attempts where OP created field separator as `,` in lines.

Comment: Why do you use a comma as separator while `=` would be a much better choice?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, from OP's post's title `Print part of a comma-separated field using AWK` I could see it's a CSV file IMHO that's why OP would have used `,`

Comment: _but get a syntax error_  is a poor description of an error. Most likely, the error message contains more information than just the two words _syntax error_.

Comment: @EverLearner: A parenthesis is missing: `{printf(a[1])}`. But prefer `print a[1]`.

Comment: @EverLearner: A parenthesis is missing and it should be index 2 when using the array. This should work:
`awk -F, '{n=split($NF,a,"="); a[n]} {printf(a[2])}'` . But tbh I would prefer the solutions mentioned already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***1st solution:*** In case you want only to get last field(which contains `=` in it) then with your shown samples please try following

```
awk -F',[[:space:]]+|=' '{print $NF}' Input_file
```

---

---

**2nd solution:** OR in case you want to get specifically 3rd field's value after `=` then try following `awk` code please. Simply making comma followed by space(s) as field separator and in main program splitting 3rd field storing values into arr array, then printing 2nd item value of arr array.

```
awk -F',[[:space:]]+' '{split($3,arr,"=");print arr[2]}' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have been more specific. In addition to the SUBCASE_1, I need to print 123 too, so I would need both , and = separator. Can you advise please?

Comment: @EverLearner, ok sure, how about using `awk -F',[[:space:]]+' '{split($3,arr,"=");print 
 $2,arr[2]}' Input_file` OR `awk -F',[[:space:]]+|=' '{print $2,$NF}'  Input_file` once, please test it and do let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: Thanks, your code did not return any value, but I modified my code and it worked.  ```awk -F, '{n=split($3,a,"="); a[n]} {print $2,a[2]}' myfile```

Answer (score 4):

Possibly the shortest solution would be:

```sh
awk -F= '{print $NF}' file
```

Where you simply use `'='` as the field-separator and then print the last field.

**Example Use/Output**

Using your sample into in a *heredoc* with the sigil quoted to prevent expansion of `$DLOAD`, you would have:

```
$ awk -F= '{print $NF}' << 'eof'
> $DLOAD , 123 , Loadcase name=SUBCASE_1
> eof
SUBCASE_1
```

(of course in this case it probably doesn't matter whether `$DLOAD` was expanded or not, but for completeness, in case `$DLOAD` included another `'='` ...)